# Inserting Data From Android to PHP file and then to Mysql error

Tags: java, android, mysql, android-intent

I'm inserting data into a mysql database with a function in my android app but it crashes every time I click the button to execute it. These are the errors I get:

10-08 16:16:05.649: E/AndroidRuntime(19038): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
10-08 16:16:05.649: E/AndroidRuntime(19038): android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException
10-08 16:16:05.649: E/AndroidRuntime(19038):    at android.os.StrictMode$AndroidBlockGuardPolicy.onNetwork(StrictMode.java:1125)
10-08 16:16:05.649: E/AndroidRuntime(19038):    at java.net.InetAddress.lookupHostByName(InetAddress.java:385)
10-08 16:16:05.649: E/AndroidRuntime(19038):    at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByNameImpl(InetAddress.java:236)
10-08 16:16:05.649: E/AndroidRuntime(19038):    at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:214)
10-08 16:16:05.649: E/AndroidRuntime(19038):    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnectionOperator.openConnection(DefaultClientConnectionOperator.java:137)
10-08 16:16:05.649: E/AndroidRuntime(19038):    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPoolEntry.open(AbstractPoolEntry.java:164)
10-08 16:16:05.649: E/AndroidRuntime(19038):    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPooledConnAdapter.open(AbstractPooledConnAdapter.java:119)
10-08 16:16:05.649: E/AndroidRuntime(19038):    at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.execute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:360)
10-08 16:16:05.649: E/AndroidRuntime(19038):    at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:670)
10-08 16:16:05.649: E/AndroidRuntime(19038):    at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:509)
10-08 16:16:05.649: E/AndroidRuntime(19038):    at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:487)
10-08 16:16:05.649: E/AndroidRuntime(19038):    at com.example.gloc.MainActivity.insert(MainActivity.java:360)
10-08 16:16:05.649: E/AndroidRuntime(19038):    at com.example.gloc.MainActivity$3.onClick(MainActivity.java:217)
10-08 16:16:05.649: E/AndroidRuntime(19038):    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4354)
10-08 16:16:05.649: E/AndroidRuntime(19038):    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:17961)
10-08 16:16:05.649: E/AndroidRuntime(19038):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:725)
10-08 16:16:05.649: E/AndroidRuntime(19038):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
10-08 16:16:05.649: E/AndroidRuntime(19038):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
10-08 16:16:05.649: E/AndroidRuntime(19038):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5328)
10-08 16:16:05.649: E/AndroidRuntime(19038):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
10-08 16:16:05.649: E/AndroidRuntime(19038):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
10-08 16:16:05.649: E/AndroidRuntime(19038):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1102)
10-08 16:16:05.649: E/AndroidRuntime(19038):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:869)
10-08 16:16:05.649: E/AndroidRuntime(19038):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)

this is my code

```
public void insert(){  
    String input_data= "http://www.wolfdoginfo.net/app/dataapp.php"; //URL website anda dengan file insert.php yang telah dibuat  

      HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();  
      HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(input_data);  
      ArrayList<NameValuePair> param = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();  
    final EditText reguser = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.usernamecomplete);
    final EditText regpass = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.passwordcomplete);
    final EditText regemail = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.email);
    String password = regpass.getText().toString();
    password =  md5(password);
      param.add(new BasicNameValuePair("username", reguser.getText().toString()));  
      param.add(new BasicNameValuePair("password", password));  
      param.add(new BasicNameValuePair("email", regemail.getText().toString())); 

      try {  
           httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(param));  
           HttpResponse httpRespose = httpClient.execute(httpPost);  
          HttpEntity httpEntity = httpRespose.getEntity();  
          InputStream in = httpEntity.getContent();  
          BufferedReader read = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));  

          String isi= "";  
          String baris= "";  

          while((baris = read.readLine())!=null){  
             isi+= baris;  
          }  

          //Jika isi tidak sama dengan "null " maka akan tampil Toast "Berhasil" sebaliknya akan tampil "Gagal"  
          if(!isi.equals("null")){                    
             Toast.makeText(this, "Berhasil", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();  
          }else{  
             Toast.makeText(this, "Gagal", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();  
          }  

    } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {  
       // TODO Auto-generated catch block  
       e.printStackTrace();  
    } catch (IOException e) {  
       // TODO Auto-generated catch block  
       e.printStackTrace();  
    }
```

}

Answer (score 0):

You need to make your HTTP request in a separate thread. You will easily find an example on SO demonstrating this. Check this out:

[Thread HTTP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6343166/android-os-networkonmainthreadexception)

Comment: ok I put it under a thread but ti still doesnt save to database.

Comment: I answered the initial question. Your PHP code is likely the culprit if your insert is not working.

Comment: Are you getting the same exception even when running the code on a seperate thread?